# Splitting up array values into 3

Tags: php, loops

I have stored navigation menu into the database and wanted to break into 3 columns col-md-3 like every 3 li will be wraped into col-md-3 let me show you it is made statically

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Careers</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Make a Booking</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Find a Store</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Terms and Conditions</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Delivery and Returns</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And all these navigation menu is in the database how do i make them dynamic I tried using for loop but not working using it

```
<?php 
    $nav = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '');
    $total = count($nav);
    $i = 1;

    for ($i; $i <= $total; $i++) {
        $ans = $i / 3;      
?>

<?php if(round($ans) == 3) {
?>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <?php for($j = 1; $j <= $ans; $j++) { ?>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $nav[$j]; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php if($i == 1) { ?>

<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
        <?php for($k = 0; $k <= $ans; $k++) { ?>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $nav[$k]; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<?php } ?>

<?php  } ?>
```

I tried using simple test using custom array values but this is not happenign what should I do in order

Comment: Use [array_chunk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: `<?php echo $nav[$j]; ?>` ur NAV does not start with 1, an Array starts with 0 just set `$j = 0; $j < $ans`

Comment: like array chukn will be placed outside loop for col-sm-3 and ul tag ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php 
$nav = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', '');
$total = count($nav);
$i     = 0;
foreach($nav as $sub) {
if($i % 3 == 0) {
  if($i != 0) { ?> </ul></div><?php }
?>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <ul>
<?php } ?>
        <li><a href=""><?php echo $sub; ?></a></li>

<?php $i++; 
} 
?>
```

Output:

- a
- b
- c

- d
- e
- f

- g
- h
- i

Comment: Thumbs up for you man great but can you please explain me why is </ul> and </div is closed at top and why not at bottom ?

Comment: You can also close at botton..but you need to set some logical coditions below..otherwise at bottom its also ok..

Comment: ok i understood the first logic but $i != 0 is bit confusing me

Comment: $i != 0 is because if its first loop - tghen we do not need to close the div tag and ul tag..right?

Comment: okay 1 got it loop div and ul tag will only be closed if it's 3 right and start if remainder is 0 ?

Comment: if you have more than 9 elements then you got a fourth column... is this expected? or should there be just more elements in each column?

Answer (score 0):

Hi You can also use this.

```
<?php
$nav=array("Careers","Services","Make a Booking","Find a Store","Blog","Contact us","Terms and Conditions","Privacy Policy","Delivery and Returns");
$data= array_chunk($nav,3);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
echo '<div class="col-sm-3"><ul>';  
    foreach($data[$i] as $menu){?>  
         <li><a href=""><?php echo $menu; ?></a></li>       
<?php } 
echo '</ul></div>';
} ?>
```